# How do I reconstruct a data-set based on unique ID

Tags: excel, spss

Looking for a solution either in excel or IBM SPSS:

[image]

I have a dataset with around 95,000 rows. Each row is one response from a participant on a particular question. For example, Row 2 is the response from participant A, on Question 1, where they indicated a score of 2. As pictured.

Ideally I need 1 line of responses per participant as pictured here:

[image]

I've tried VLOOKUP and then a macro to delete #N/A and move up the values but memory can't even handle the VLOOKUP, so it's not a viable option.

I feel out of options on what to do, but without laying out my data-set like this, I can't do later analysis (Later I need to average across all participants where Q5 = 80 etc [Q5 is a category code]).

Comment: Just use a Pivot Table

Comment: Thank you so much Ron - can't believe it was that simple. You are a legend. Just figuring out how to mark this as answered.

Comment: I posted an answer you can mark as answered.  Tks

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a Pivot Table.

Using `Power Query` (Excel 2010+) (aka `Get&Transform` in Excel 2016+) gives you a bit more flexibility in, for example, automating the naming of the column Headers.

You can use the GUI if you will only have five questions.  But if the number of questions might vary from run to run, the code to handle that needs to be done through the Advanced Editor.

If not, you can use the GUI to just Pivot the QuestionNumber column

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"UserID", type text}, {"QuestionNumber", Int64.Type}, {"Score", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"QuestionNumber", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"QuestionNumber", type text}}, "en-US")[QuestionNumber]), "QuestionNumber", "Score", List.Sum),
    Renames = List.Transform(List.Skip(Table.ColumnNames(#"Pivoted Column"),1), each {_, "Q" &_}),
    #"New Headers" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Pivoted Column", Renames)
in
    #"New Headers"
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**SPSS ANSWER:**
Run this code in a new syntax window:

```
casestovars /id=userid /index=questionNum /separator="".
```